Angular Material 17 Typography Styles
How does one get the typography level styles inside a custom component in Angular Material v17?
$config: mat.define-typography-config($font-family: 'Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif', $headline-1: mat-typography-level(112px, 112px, 300, $letter-spacing: -0.05em), $display-3: mat-typography-level(56px, 56px, 400, $letter-spacing: -0.02em), $display-2: mat-typography-level(45px, 48px, 400, $letter-spacing: -0.005em), $display-1: mat-typography-level(34px, 40px, 400), $headline: mat-typography-level(24px, 32px, 400), $title: mat-typography-level(20px, 32px, 500), $subheading-2: mat-typography-level(16px, 28px, 400), $subheading-1: mat-typography-level(15px, 24px, 400), $body-2: mat-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500), $body-1: mat-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400), $caption: mat-typography-level(12px, 20px, 400), $button: mat-typography-level(14px, 14px, 500), $input: mat-typography-level(inherit, 1.125, 400));
@include mat.all-component-typographies($config);


@mixin expansion-panel-group-typography($config) {
  .expansion-panel-group-header {           
    @include mat.typography-level-to-styles($config,subheading-1);
   }
}

What is the workaround? How do I get custom typography working? Is mat.typography-level-to-styles still available for v17?
